# How to convert to/from a CorelDraw .WI wavelet-compressed image file

Tags: image-processing, file-compression, file-converter

I have a large sample of .WI images I need to convert to e.g. JPEGs, but the format now seems defunct.

The mimetype is image/wavelet.

The compression algorithm was developed by Summus, a US company that also now seems defunct.

The last CorelDraw support for the format was under 32-bit Windows. If I go down the hardware route I need to be able to make calls to a server via e.g. REST.

I think under *nix djvulibre might be able to open the files, but I haven't been able to test this yet.

Another option is to re-implement the codec myself.

Does anyone here have any expertise in this area?

Apologies if this is not the right forum - is there a better place?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: The question is definitely on-topic here if you change your text from *how to open* to *software to convert from/to*.

Comment: You are crossposting (see also https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5544/how-to-open-a-coreldraw-wi-wavelet-compressed-image), please [don't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). I suggest you delete that other question.

Comment: Only 32-bit versions of CorelDraw support .wi images (presumably due to Corel being dependent on an old licensed library that there is only a 32-bit versions of and no corresponding source code for) but that's not the same as only being supported under 32-bit Windows -- x64 versions of Windows can run most 32-bit Windows software (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/running-32-bit-applications for more information)

Comment: @jtlz2 any luck with this? I need to create a wavelet from raw bytes and then covert to a jpeg. Looking for some direction :/